# Is there a way to make a Venn diagram in Word 2007?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007

How can I draw a Venn diagram in Word 2007? All that happens when I make 2 circles is two overlapping circles.

Comment: [Create a Venn diagram](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Create-a-Venn-diagram-d746a2ce-ed61-47a7-93fe-7c101940839d)

Comment: Cool! I would rather have this as an answer....

Comment: Feel free to [answer your own question?](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer). I haven't got the time right now to write it up properly.